# Is $T(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\lambda(k)\Lambda(k)}{k} \geq 0$ and what is the upper bound of $T(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \lambda(n)\Lambda(n) $?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, arithmetic-functions

Let $\Lambda(n)$ denote the von Mangoldt function: $\Lambda(n)=\log p$ when $n=p^e$ is a prime power ($e\ge 1$) and $\Lambda(n)=0$ otherwise.
and $\lambda(n)$ be [Liouville Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function), , I'm interested to know about average growth of the following function $T_j(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\lambda(n)\Lambda(n)}{n^j} $ such that I want to determine its upper bound for large $n$ , Probably it is known that positivity of $T(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\lambda(k)}{k} $ for large $n$ is an open problem such that its confirmation led to proof of the Riemann hypothesis according to Pál Turán ,My two dependents questions are :

> > **Question**:

a) Is  $T(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\lambda(k)\Lambda(k)}{k} \geq 0$  (Does this sum also  behave like related sum to [Pólya conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture)  )

b) What is the upper bound of  $T_j(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\lambda(n)\Lambda(n)}{n^j} $ , take the case $j=0$?

**Note**: The motivation of this question is to look if the positivity of the titled sum also led to proof of Riemann hypothesis

Comment: This question makes no sense:  If $n =p^e$ is a prime power (so usually $e=1$) then $\lambda(n) =(-1)^e$ which is usually just $-1$.